# Apache Accumulo 2.0.1 with Zookeeper versions 3.5 and later

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I need to update a docker stack containing a container for Apache Accumulo and one for Zookeeper. The old Dockerfile for Accumulo is something like this.

```
FROM hdfs-custom-image

ARG TAG
ARG ZOOKEEPER_VERSION
ARG ACCUMULO_VERSION


# Install Zookeeper
ENV ZOOKEEPER_VERSION ${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}
ENV ZOOKEEPER_HOME /opt/zookeeper
ENV ZOOKEEPER_DATA /data/zookeeper
ENV ZOOKEEPER_CONF_DIR $ZOOKEEPER_HOME/conf
ENV ZOO_LOG4J_PROP WARN,CONSOLE
ENV PATH $PATH:$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin
ENV ACCUMULO_HOME=/opt/accumulo
ENV PATH="$PATH:/opt/accumulo/bin"

RUN set -x \
    && mkdir -p $ZOOKEEPER_HOME $ZOOKEEPER_DATA  \
    && curl -# https://archive.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}/apache-zookeeper-${ZOOKEEPER_VERSION}.tar.gz  \
    | tar -xz -C ${ZOOKEEPER_HOME} --strip-components=1


# Install Accumulo
ENV ACCUMULO_VERSION ${ACCUMULO_VERSION}
ENV ACCUMULO_HOME /opt/accumulo
ENV ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR $ACCUMULO_HOME/conf
ENV PATH=$PATH:$ACCUMULO_HOME/bin

ADD accumulo-${ACCUMULO_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz /opt

RUN set -x \
  && mv /opt/accumulo-${ACCUMULO_VERSION} ${ACCUMULO_HOME} \
  && yum install -y make gcc-c++ \
#  && bash -c "${ACCUMULO_HOME}/bin/build_native_library.sh" \  # This file is not present in Accumulo-2.0.1
  && yum -y autoremove gcc-c++

WORKDIR "${ACCUMULO_HOME}"

COPY ./fs/sbin /sbin
COPY ./fs/opt /opt

ENTRYPOINT [ "/sbin/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

This works for Accumulo version 1.9.3 and Zookeeper version 3.4.8. I am trying to upgrade the versions to 2.0.1 and 3.8.1, respectively, but Accumulo fails to detect Zookeeper. The reason is explained in the official Accumulo guide.

https://accumulo.apache.org/release/accumulo-2.0.1/

I have tried setting some environment variables differently, but Accumulo still does not detect Zookeeper.
Are there any configurations to add or change in the Dockerfile or docker-compose?

Comment: Without knowing *what* you changed when you say you "tried setting...differently", it's hard to guess as to what you might have done wrong. One important bit is that the structure of the ZooKeeper distribution changed in 3.5, so you need to update your classpath accordingly. In any case, Accumulo 2.1.0 is available now as an LTM release, and defaults to using newer versions of ZooKeeper, so you should probably just use 2.1.0 instead of the non-LTM 2.0.1 version. Also, this question would be better suited to [the Accumulo mailing list](https://accumulo.apache.org/contact-us/).

Comment: I tried changing the path for the Zookeeper configuration in the accumulo-site.xml file, from $ZOOKEEPER_HOME/zookeeper[^.].*.jar to $ZOOKEEPER_HOME/lib/zookeeper[^.].*.jar, since the jars were moved right into the lib directory. I also tried Accumulo 2.1.0, but it still doesn't work. @Christopher

Comment: I'd recommend reaching out to the Accumulo mailing list for additional help figuring out what's wrong. It's the best way to get help with something like this. https://accumulo.apache.org/contact-us